# Is it ok to make all methods called from a servlet doGet() static to avoid synchronization?

Tags: servlets, concurrency, static, synchronized

I have a servlet which performs various business logic. I want to avoid synchronisation like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest _req, final HttpServletResponse _resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
     synchronized (MyServlet.class) {
         various();
         calls();
         and_logic(_req, _resp);
     }
}
```

by making all called methods static and enforcing it like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest _req, final HttpServletResponse _resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    _doGet(_req, _resp);
}

private static void _doGet(final HttpServletRequest _req, final HttpServletResponse _resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
     various();
     calls();
     and_logic(_req, _resp);
}
```

I won't use any static variables and all my method calls are assumed to be thread-safe. Are there any non-obvious drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I won't use any static variables and all my method calls are assumed to be thread-safe.

Under these conditions neither you don't need synchronization nor static methods. Just use instance methods of a servlet or some other service class.

Comment: Fair enough, the static method is just there to ensure that I or someone else working on the code won't accidentally use or introduce instance variables.

Comment: @StefanSeidel So what is to stop them from introducing static variables? I really think you're barking up the wrong tree here.